# private messaging (Android)

Tags: php, android, android-fragments, android-studio, private-messaging

I am developing an android app, it is a social media app with many features. One of the features is a private messaging between users. What is the best way to do it. 
Note: I'm using PHP for the backend of the app.

Comment: Very broad, very opinion-based. No right answer. Unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Perhaps try posting this in the android enthusiasts at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can Achieve it
You should take a look at [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) 
It would help you create a Real time Chat Feature between a Single User and Multiple User

Also with [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) Capability you can also provide feature like Uploading Pictures and Videos